# Magento 2.4.x: Get stripe payment status on admin grid

Tags: magento2, order-grid, status, stripe

Is there a way to get the stripe payment status on custom sales order grid column?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show Payment Status as Succeeded for an order if **total_paid** and **last_trans_id** is not null in **sales_order_payment** table.

Answer (score 0):

1. UI component `sales_order_grid.xml` under `[COMPANY]/[MODULE]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml` add below code

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"><columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="stripe_payment_status" class="[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Stripe Payment Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns></listing>
   ```
2. Then created the UI class under `[COMPANY]/[MODULE]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php` add

`Below Code`

```
<?php namespace [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $status = $order->getData("stripe_payment_status"); // customize code add here status which is came in the order view page

                   
                // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return export_status
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $status;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

3. The value which coming here in below screenshot :
   [image]

That value you have to bind with `$status = $order->getData("stripe_payment_status");` $status variable.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: @mechanic Mark this answer useful if it works for you

Comment: It is not working. The status value is empty.

Comment: what you have in this line $status = $order->getData("stripe_payment_status");

Comment: That is what I want to know, how do I bind the stripe payment status with $status = $order->getData("stripe_payment_status");?

Comment: Oh, So you not able to get this information though order object?
can you send me print_r($order->getData()); information ?
That payment status you can check stripe module as well and from there you can do same way in above code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The value is coming from the Stripe API.
Please see `\StripeIntegration\Payments\Block\PaymentInfo\Element::getPaymentStatus`

The status of payment is pulled using the last transaction id as a param in the API, which is coming from the order additional info. I suggest you follow the method to see more in depth whats happening.

You could create your own method which gets the order id as an input, get the last transaction id of that order, and basically do a API request to Stripe using that transaction id as a param to determine the status of payment.

For how to render the status in the order dropdown, please follow @Saurabh Dwivedi answer. You basically have to set $status to the response you get from the API.

Note: this is based on stripe/module-payments, version 3.3.8.

Hope it helps!